# general approach for race detection and optimization

Tags: concurrency, detection, race-condition

I have a multi-threaded programs in C++, which consists of some data race regions. Is there any approach to automatically (I mean, not manually check) find out these data race regions that may cause access conflicts in execution? I know there is a lot of tools to help me out and a lot of research papers about this problem. I just want to know what are these general approaches and what are the main ideas of them basically? I would appreciate it a lot if you could tell me more in perspective of programming language.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, for me the most promising aproach is to trace all concurrent accesses to a field. An then check if they can be ordered according to the java memory model. If everything can be ordered you have proved that no data race has happened.

Still races can appear because of non atomic access to those fields. Here I don't see how this could be checked automatically. I think a overview for the programmer of what fields are accesses atomic would be helpful.